# Flutter - CircleAvatar not updating

Tags: flutter

I have this home screen where the user profile image is shown and in settings screen the user is able to change that image. The problem is that when going back from settings to home screen the image doesn't update.

```dart
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  late User _user;
  String _userImage = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _user = _firebaseAuth.currentUser!;
    _userImage = _user.photoURL!;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        actions: [
          Tooltip(
            message: "Settings",
            child: IconButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                await Navigator.pushNamed(context, routeSettings);
                setState(() {
                  _userImage = _user.photoURL!;
                  print("changed: $_userImage");
                });
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings_rounded),
            ),
          ),
          CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: kBrownColor,
            backgroundImage:
                _userImage.isNotEmpty ? NetworkImage(_userImage) : null,
            child: _userImage.isEmpty
                ? Text(
                    getInitials(_user.displayName!),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: kWhiteColor,
                    ),
                  )
                : null,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm getting the url of the image in the console when printing it inside setState() when going back to this screen but the CircleAvatar doesn't load it.

Answer (score 0):

pass parameter when pop() from setting screen

```
   onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop({
      'avatar': 'image_url',
   }),
```

and button in HomeScreen

```
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            var data = await Navigator.pushNamed(context, routeSettings);
            setState(() {
              _userImage = data['avatar'];
            });
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.settings_rounded),
        ),
```

Comment: I did something better: I used a static variable.
Because I'm not popping the screen explicitly. The back button in the AppBar and the one in the android device itself are doing it.

Answer (score 0):

İf you are reaching to settings page without deleting the homepage from memory it won't change automatically since it just draws another screen on top of another. So the init state won't work again after you update the image on the settings page. There are multiple solutions for this but the easiest as I see would be clearing all stacks and inserting the homepage again. To clear stack you may use Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil().

With named route

```
  Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, '/home', (route) => false);
```

Without named route

```
  Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()), (route) => false);
```

This should do the trick.